# how can we make the container next to fixed left navigation bar responsive?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrapping

I'm trying to implement a UI where **the navigation bar on the LHS is fixed and the content window is responsive**. The following is my implementation:

```
<div style="width: 15%; float: left; display: inline;>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-left" style="">
    NAVIGATION CONTENT HERE (FIXED)
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div style="width: 85%; float: right; display: inline;">
    DESIRED RESPONSIVE CONTENT HERE
 </div>
```

how can this be achieved?

I tried using bootstrap classes by adding a container on the top and adding column classes to both the div's. The div on the right overlaps the navbar div when the browser window size is reduced.

Comment: Add your css and combine both html and css into a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to implement such a design? Left-sidebar with fixed width and the  content with variable width? It would be much easier and faster to just use bootstrap table grid system. Not to mention that it would automatically work on all devices and resolution, whereas your design would only make sense on some particular resolutions.

Comment: I already tried using column classes (col-md-2 and col-md-10 inside container class) to implement this. Any help with that is also welcome as it's always the better solution.

Comment: And why is `col-md-2` and `col-md-10` not suitable for you?

Answer (score 0):

used the following way to fix my side navbar:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_fixed

1. fixed the navbar with 15% width.
2. added bootstrap classes to the content on the RHS.